# Does Largest Target affect only whoever uniquely has the most HP?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

The Largest Target Crossfire card says

> At the start of each turn, if any runner has more HP than the others,
>   that runner takes 1 damage.

Does this mean that each turn if there is a single runner with more HP than every other runner, he takes 1 damage? Brutal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This card only affects a player when they have the highest HP and aren't tied with someone else.**

So, this is one of those weird phrases in games that's always used but doesn't make any sense as to why it gets used still.  What' we're looking for is the relationship between hp of players.

At the start of the turn, let's say I have 5 and Jim has 6 HP.  Jim will take 1 damage, since he has more hp than the other runner in the game.  At the start of the next round, we both have 5 HP, and nobody takes damage because nobody has more HP than anyone else.

For a more complex example, lets' say I have 4, Tina has 3, Jim has 4, and Al has 2.  In this case, I have more HP than Tin and Al, but not Jim.  I won't take damage.  Jim will say the same, since he's got the same HP as me, and more than Tina and Al.

Comment: From what I have read while searching for this the card has been updated to say on ties no damage is dealt but I can't find a picture of the card.